# Use MainLayout.razor instead of _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm working on Blazor app with scaffolded Identity.

Problem is, Identity has own Layout with Navbars and Containers using Bootstrap, in other hand Blazor has his own Navigation look.

Is there chance to render identity views in `MainLayout.razor`, not in `_Layout.cshtml`, I don't find useful to have multiple layouts (Register, Login, Forgot Password..) different than the whole Blazor app pages.

I can import same classes and write same things, but, is there way to render Identity Login page in MainLayout.razor.

I know that cshtml can't render razor, but it other way it work.

Question is how can I switch `_Layout.cshtml` to the `MainLayout.razor` and have unified layout for Identity views and my pages/views?

Comment: The equivalent would be `_Host.cshtml`, not `MainLayout.razor`.

Comment: @Henk Holterman can you elaborate? Because doesn't work when I put _Host for my idnetity layout

Comment: No, of course that won't work. Not witrhout a lot of modification anyway. But study those files, MainLayout is out of scope so there is little to gain. Just style them to look similar, it's only two sets.